# Safari sending empty file to server on File upload via FormData

Tags: javascript, safari

We're trying to upload an blob of an image that's been cropped.

The following code works in Chrome and Firefox, however we're having issues with Safari.

The `File` appears to well formed before it is appended to the `FormData` unfortunately Safari does not give enough support to view the file once attached to the `FormData`

Our problem is that once it's sent to our server dumping out `var_dump( $_FILES['file'] )` shows the file to empty (it's size property is 0).

I believe this to be down Safari's "basic" support of FormData, but Polyfillers I've tried to use have not resolved the issue.  Is there a way around this?

```
// From Controller
$scope.uploadImage = function( croppedImage ) {
  $scope.uploadingImage = true;
  var imageBlob = dataURItoBlob( croppedImage );
  var options = {
    action: 'upload_file',
    format: 'media_item',
    output: 'json'
  }

  var file = new File( [ imageBlob ], $scope.filename,{
    type: 'image/png'
  });

  console.log( file.size );

  MediaService.uploadImage( file, options ).then(
    function( response ) {
      $modalInstance.close( response );
    }
  ).finally(
    function() {
      $scope.uploadingImage = false;
    }
  )
};

// From MediaService (angular service
uploadImage: function( image, params ){
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append( 'action', params.action );
  formData.append( 'format', params.format);
  formData.append( 'file', image );

  //The POST header needs to be multipart/form-data
  $http.defaults.headers.post = {};

  return $http( {
    method: 'POST',
    url: apiMediaUrl,
    data: formData,
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
    withCredentials: true
  } )
  .then(
    function( response ) {
      return response.data.payload;
    },
    function( errorResponse ) {
      throw errorResponse.data.payload || errorResponse.data;
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: try to change `MediaService.uploadImage( file, options )` to `MediaService.uploadImage( imageBlob, options )`, if not work then provide the result of `console.log(imageBlob)` and `console.log(file)`

Comment: Ha, we literally just got this, previously our api was rejecting them.  But if we pass `uploadImage` the filename and `formData.append( 'file', image, filename );` It works.  Couple of other kinks to work out, but they should be easy.
Thanks!

Comment: So your problem solved?

Comment: Yes, thanks! My colleague owes me a pint haha.
I'll be happy to accept an answer if you post it as one

Comment: Please add as your answer, this will be useful to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day of pulling my hair out, finally got this.

By sending the `imageBlob` instead of creating a `new File` to the MediaService and the appending a filename.

So

```
// From Controller
$scope.uploadImage = function( croppedImage ) {
  $scope.uploadingImage = true;
  var imageBlob = dataURItoBlob( croppedImage );
  var options = {
    action: 'upload_file',
    format: 'media_item',
    output: 'json',
    params: 'filename'
  }

  // no longer convert to file

  MediaService.uploadImage( imageBlob, options ).then(
    function( response ) {
      $modalInstance.close( response );
    }
  ).finally(
    function() {
      $scope.uploadingImage = false;
    }
  )
};

// From MediaService (angular service
uploadImage: function( image, params ){
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append( 'action', params.action );
  formData.append( 'format', params.format);

  /*
   *  Add file name here
   */
  formData.append( 'file', image, params.filename );

  //The POST header needs to be multipart/form-data
  $http.defaults.headers.post = {};

  return $http( {
    method: 'POST',
    url: apiMediaUrl,
    data: formData,
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
    withCredentials: true
  } )
  .then(
    function( response ) {
      return response.data.payload;
    },
    function( errorResponse ) {
      throw errorResponse.data.payload || errorResponse.data;
    }
  );
}
```